# DLL file not updated when publishing web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, publish

I make updates in my web site code behind and then run Publish.
The dll file is created but the modified date value remains a few months back, and the changes are not applied when I copy the dll file to the server.

The changes are very minor, like changing an if statement and updating an initial value of a variable.

What is the explanation?

Thank You.

Comment: Are you making major changes to the code?  Are you working on a Web Site or Web Application?  What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: It's a Web Site, .NET 2.0. The changes are minor but should make an impact.

Comment: Could you update the post with the changes you are attempting to make?

Comment: Updated the post with the changes.

Comment: Have you tried a Clean operation?  I'd run a Clean, then if the DLL is still there, delete it and rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting temporary asp.net files  and then re-publish the application.

You can find temporary ASP.NET Files in below path
 `c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

From this location just delete your application. If you cannot delete the files, restart the IIS or stop the worker process (w3wp.exe)

After that just republish your site

Comment: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your AssemblyInfo.cs that there is a correct versioning and so on.

There you can set the current Date as Publishing date and it works