# Finding out why my published dll is different from the one I'm debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

Running Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, I have a large .NET MVC project that I have troubles debugging part of. I debug it while attaching to the IIS (on the same machine), but for some projects, I have troubles getting the breakpoints to bind.

During the process of investigating this, I have noticed that the size of a particular dll, representing a project I have a hard time debugging, is different when published to IIS on the same machine, compared to what is produced in the bin folder when just building the project within Visual Studio.

Project `Foo` refers to project `Bar`. The publish settings for Foo has `<LastUsedBuildConfiguration>` set to `BAZ`. It is this project I publish to IIS.

But when I build Foo (or Bar, for that matter), using any conceivable build configuration, it is binary different from the version in IIS.

How do I find out why?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your build directory?

Comment: Yes, I have cleaned it.

Comment: rather than attacking this by working out why it ISNT using the same lib as in your debug configuration.  Can you find out what it is using and where that is coming from.

Comment: Failing that, take a copy of your debug library, search the project directory for all instances of that library and overwrite them with the debug .dll file

Comment: Have you tried use the same build configuration as the value in `<LastUsedBuildConfiguration>` when you debugging that porject?

Comment: @Christofer Ohlsson, What about this issue? How did you compare the two dll file, just the size or others? What are the differences? I also agree with Larry and leo suggestions, please make sure that you really publish your project using the same mode during you debug, another possible reason is that you have updated your app after you publish it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273164/dll-file-not-updated-when-publishing-web-site. If you get any latest information, please feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

What may be happening is that you are publishing a 'Release' version of the DLL and you are debugging a 'Debug' version.  The Debug version of the DLL is going to be larger, not be optimized, and have an associated PDB [(symbol)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/01/05/understanding-symbol-files-and-visual-studios-symbol-settings/) file.

Comment: I cannot produce an identical version of the dll, no matter the build config.